# How to implement an interface class using the non-virtual interface idiom in C++?

Tags: c++, interface, idioms, non-virtual-interface

In C++ an interface can be implemented by a class whose methods are pure virtual.

Such a class could be part of a library to describe what methods an object should implement to be able to work with other classes in the library:

```
class Lib::IFoo
{
    public:
        virtual void method() = 0;
};
```

:

```
class Lib::Bar
{
    public:
        void stuff( Lib::IFoo & );
};
```

Now I want to to use class `Lib::Bar`, so I have to implement the `IFoo` interface.

For my purposes I need a whole of related classes so I would like to work with a base class that guarantees common behavior using the NVI idiom:

```
class FooBase : public IFoo // implement interface IFoo
{
    public:
        void method(); // calls methodImpl;

    private:
        virtual void methodImpl();
};
```

The non-virtual interface (NVI) idiom ought to deny derived classes the possibility of overriding the common behavior implemented in `FooBase::method()`, but since `IFoo` made it virtual it seems that all derived classes have the opportunity to override the `FooBase::method()`.

If I want to use the NVI idiom, what are my options other than the pImpl idiom already suggested (thanks space-c0wb0y).

Answer (score 6):

I think you've got your NVI pattern around the wrong way: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Not sure if that solves your issue though.

```
class IFoo
{
    public:
       void method() { methodImpl(); }
    private:
       virtual void methodImpl()=0;
};

class FooBase : public IFoo // implement interface IFoo
{
    private:
        virtual void methodImpl();
};
```

Here's an example of why you might do this using a reader that reads from XML and another from DB. Note that common structure is moved into the NVI readFromSource, while non-common behaviour is moved into the private virtual getRawDatum. This way logging and error checking is only needed in the one function.

```
class IReader
{
  public:
    // NVI
    Datum readFromSource()
    {
       Datum datum = getRawDatum();
       if( ! datum.isValid() ) throw ReaderError("Unable to get valid datum");
       logger::log("Datum Read");
       return datum;
    }
  private:
    // Virtual Bits
    Datum getRawDatum()=0;
};

class DBReader : public IReader
{
  private:
    Datum getRawDatum() { ... }
};

class XmlReader : public IReader
{
   private:
     Datum getRawDatum() { ... }
};
```

Comment: I would like to work with an interface class that *only* prescribes the methods any implementation of that interface should offer, and a base class that guarantees some commonality in the behavior of its derived classes by using the NVI idiom (aka template method). I could have two completely different base classes, one that interfaces with an XML file, and one that interfaces with a RDBMS for example. They implement IFoo, and have to guarantee some commonality in behavior of derived classes.

Comment: @andreas: In C++, interfaces are described by using (possibly abstract) base classes which declare (possibly pure) virtual functions. Derived classes then implement those virtual functions by overriding them. Any virtual member function of the base class can be overridden in _any_ derived classes. Therefor the NVI can only be implemented in the _base_ class, by implementing _non-virtual_ methods. If you want a two-layer approach, simple NVI won't work, since classes derived from the common base classes (which derive from the interface) can override all the interface's virtual functions.

Comment: @andreas I've added an example that does what you describe in your comment. Hope that makes sense. I think you want more than this though .. but I'm not sure what exactly. Maybe you should extend your question further with a full example of 1) What you'd like to be able to do, and/or 2) What is going wrong with the normal NVI?

Answer (score 4):

Commonly, the reason for using the NVI (sometimes also called "Template Method") is that derived classes should only change *a part* of the base class' behavior. So what you do is this:

```
class base {
  public:
    void f()
    {
      // do something derived classes shouldn't interfere with          
      vf();
      // do something derived classes shouldn't interfere with          
      vg();
      // do something derived classes shouldn't interfere with          
      vh();
      // do something derived classes shouldn't interfere with          
    }
  private:
    virtual void vf(); // might be pure virtual, too
    virtual void vg(); // might be pure virtual, too
    virtual void vh(); // might be pure virtual, too
};
```

Derived classes can then plug into `f()` at the spots they are meant to and change *aspects* of `f()`'s behavior, without messing up its fundamental algorithm.

Comment: Completely true, but how can I get the base class to implement an interface without losing the guarantees (about the order of execution of vf, vg and vh for example) that my template method offers?

Comment: @andreas: I've answered to your comment to Michael's answer. I suggest you extend your question so that it describes a little better what you want to do. From what I understand, maybe mix-ins or policies might be what you're looking for.

Comment: NVI and Template Method are completely different concepts; though NVI is how Template Method is typically implemented. You could just as simply have a Template Method that uses a strategy object for it's virtuals, and you could just as simply have an NVI pattern that's not for the Template Method pattern.

Comment: +1 for simple and small code that illustrates perfectly why one would use the NVI pattern.

Answer (score 2):

It may be confusing that once a method is declared as virtual in a base class, it automatically becomes virtual in all derived classes, even if the `virtual` keywords is not used there. So in your example, both methods of `FooBase` are virtual.

> ... to deny derived classes the
>   possibility of overriding the common
>   behavior implemented in
>   FooBase::method()...

If you can get rid of `IFoo`, and just start the hierarchy with `FooBase` with a non-virtual `method`, that would do it. But it looks like you want to allow direct children of `IFoo` to override `method()`, but to prevent children of `FooBase` to override it. I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pimpl-idiom to achieve this:

```
class IFoo
{
    public:
        IFoo( boost::shared_ptr< IFooImpl > pImpl )
            : m_pImpl( pImpl )
        {}

        void method() { m_pImpl->method(); }
        void otherMethod() { m_pImpl->otherMethod(); }
    private:
        boost::shared_ptr< IFooImpl > m_pImpl;
};

class IFooImpl
{
    public:
        void method();
        virtual void otherMethod();
};
```

Now others can still subclass `IFooImpl` and pass it to `IFoo`, but they cannot override the behavior of `method` (they can override `otherMethod`). You can even make `IFooImpl` a direct subclass of `IFoo` and use [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) to initialize `IFoo` correctly. This is just the gist of the method. There are many ways to tweak this approach. For instance you can use the [factory-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) to make sure `IFoo`s are created correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm.. this seems like a lot of overhead and machinery to avoid having a private virtual function....

Comment: The problem is that any virtual function, even the private ones, can be overriden by subclasses. This option does have a lot of boilerplate, true, but it is bulletproof. So it is a trade-off.