# How to change variable initializated depend on virtual function

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

```
class Base{
protected:
    int remainItems = 0;
public:
    Base(){}
    virtual int numOfItem() = 0;
};
class Deveried1 : public Base{
public: 
    Deveried1() :Base(){ remainItems = numOfItem(); }
    int numOfItem(){
        return 5;
    }
};
class Deveried2 : public Base{
public:
    Deveried2() :Base(){ remainItems = numOfItem(); }
    int numOfItem(){
        return 10;
    }
};
class Deveried3 : public Base{
public:
    Deveried3() :Base(){ remainItems = numOfItem(); }
    int numOfItem(){
        return 10;
    }
};
int main(){
    Base* foo = new Deveried3;
}
```

With this design, for every deveried class, I must do the same thing in constructor to initalize remainItems. I'd like to know if there are some better way/pattern in this situation.

Comment: You can't call virtual functions in a base class constructor.

Comment: What is that method for? Can't you just create a second base class contructor taking `remainItems` as a parameter?

Comment: That method used to store numofItem for different Deveried classes, so at the beginning, remainItems = numofItem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I knew that. That is the reason I  moved it into every Deveried classes's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any benefit in the method, so I removed it and added an option to pass the variable in the base class constructor:

```
class Base{
protected:
    int remainItems;
public:
    Base(remainItems = 0) { this->remainItems = remainItems; }
};

class Deveried1 : public Base{
public: 
    Deveried1() :Base(5){}
    }
};

class Deveried2 : public Base{
public:
    Deveried2() :Base(10){}
    }
};

class Deveried3 : public Base{
public:
    Deveried3() :Base(10){}
    }
};

int main(){
    Base* foo = new Deveried3;
}
```

Comment: Because polymorphism is only applied to methods, not variable. So "numOfItem()" is used instead const numOfItem

Comment: @user2477 I don't think I understand your comment. Does your code allow anything this code would not?

Comment: Your code is correctly (only with my sample code). I just explain why i use numOfItem() instead of a magic number (benefit for readability), numOfItem is used in many places, not only in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can't call derived class functions from the base class constructor, so this kind of twisted inversion of dependencies can't work. I'd pass the value to the base-class constructor:

```
Base(int numOfItems) : remainItems(nomOfItems) {}
Derived1() : Base(5) {}
Derived2() : Base(10) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is called the **Non-Virtual Interface** pattern.

[How to implement an interface class using the non-virtual interface idiom in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735563/how-to-implement-an-interface-class-using-the-non-virtual-interface-idiom-in-c)