# Ensure abstract bass class is a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have an abstract base class:

```
struct Base : std::enable_shared_from_this<Base> 
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    void bar() {
        baz(shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

The only valid use case for `Base` is to live in a `shared_ptr` - `bar` is an important method. How can I ensure that the following is impossible:

```
struct BadDerived : Base {
    void foo() override { ... }
};

BadDerived bd;
bd.bar();
```

Comment: Have you though about using a non virtual interface?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2735596/4342498

Comment: If there were a way to do this, `enable_shared_from_this` already would do it, and your class would get it for free.

Comment: @vsoftco I don't want to be able to construct `Base` outside of a `shared_ptr` so that `bar()` can't be called outside of a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Is making the constructor private and providing a factory function not an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One technique is to make the constructor of `Base` private and `friend` a factory class or method:

```
struct Base : std::enable_shared_from_this<Base> 
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    void bar() {
        baz(shared_from_this());
    }

private:
    template<class Impl> friend std::shared_ptr<Base> makeDerived();
    Base() {}
};

template<class Impl>
std::shared_ptr<Base> makeDerived() {
    struct Derived : Base, Impl {
        void foo() override { Impl::foo(static_cast<Base*>(this)); }
    };
    return std::make_shared<Derived>();
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Impl {
    void foo(Base* self) { std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl; }
};
auto gd = makeDerived<Impl>();
gd->bar();
```

This does require you to rewrite any existing derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [ecatmur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684556/2069064), we could also make `Base` constructible from a type that only has a private constructor:

```
class PrivateT {
    PrivateT() { }

    template <typename Impl, typename... Args>
    friend std::shared_ptr<Impl> makeDerived(Args&&... );
};

struct Base : std::enable_shared_from_this<Base> {
    Base(PrivateT ) { }
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    void bar() {
        baz(shared_from_this());
    }
};

template <typename Impl, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<Impl> makeDerived(Args&&... args) {
    return std::make_shared<Impl>(std::forward<Args>(args)...,
        PrivateT{});
}
```

Every `Derived` type will have to take an extra constructor argument of type `PrivateT` that it will have to forward through... but it will still be able to inherit from `Base`!

```
struct Impl : Base {
    Impl(PrivateT pt) : Base(pt) { }
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl; }
};

auto gd = makeDerived<Impl>();
gd->bar();
```

Comment: why not use the handle body idiom? if you say it only makes sense to be a shared pointer, instead of a friend function use a constructor. and have the object the shared pointer as composition. that way nobody sees the shared pointer and you can enforce this policy.

Comment: http://ideone.com/41O3s7 played around with it. the main thing it should make is keep people from typing `x = *Base` because the pointer is inaccessible. but it's merely syntactic sugar.

Comment: I wanted to fold the factory function into the same class as the `shared_ptr` and using the class constructor as the factory function. But this does only work if the constructor call without `<>` is unique, because `BaseHandle<Foo>()` is not an allowed constructor call.